# how to use store define in store folder

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha-touch. I was wondering how to properly use the file structure in sencha-touch. For example, under the app folder there's your controller, model, profile, store, view folders. If I define a store, for example under the the store folder I create a file named search.js

```
Ext.define('Volunteer.store.search'{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['Volunteer.model.person'],
    config:{
        model: 'Volunteer.model.person'
    }
});
```

How do I use this store in a different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your store in app.js file `stores: ['search']` and different file you call `Ext.getStore('search');`. If not found, you need add search.js into index.html

Comment: I figured out how to do this. you can use Ext.Loader.config({ paths: 'model' : 'app/model/);. Then use Ext.require('model.login',function())